# Add the ability to sort questions by number of times they are favorited

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, profile-page, bookmarks

At the user profile page, the list of a user's questions can be sorted (like answers) by votes, activity, and newest, and (unlike answers) also by views. Please add the ability to sort questions by "favorites", i.e., the number of times they are favorited.

[image]

Comment: Is there a use for that type of sorting?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Detecting patterns with regard to the sort of questions that are favorited. Checking if a question nearly fulfills a badge requirement. Basically, a use similar to the use of sorting by view.